# Monotonicity of the sum/product/max of two monotone functions

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

Suppose two monotone functions $f$ and $g$ (both weakly increasing or both weakly decreasing) are given. How can it be shown that $f+g, f \cdot g, \max(f,g)$ is again monotone (either weakly increasing or weakly decreasing)? Is there a reference to a text book?

Comment: You could start by working from the definition -- what have you tried?

Comment: The one for the product is the only one that is false, consider $f=g$ and $f(x)=x$.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to mention that $f$ and $g$ are defined on $\mathbb{N}$. So, I guess also product should work.

Comment: @FrankMerzen $f(x) = x-2 = g(x)$. Then $(fg)(x) = (x-2)^2$, not quite monotone even on $\mathbb{N}$. You'd need something like $f,g$ both being non-negative, at first glance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f,g$ bi monotonuous increasing functions on the domain $D$.

Then for all $x,y \in D$ with $x \leq y$ we know that $f(x)\leq f(y)$ and $g(x) \leq g(x)$.

If we add those inequalities, we get $f(x)+g(x) \leq f(y)+g(y)$ which is equivalent to $(f+g)(x) \leq (f+g)(y)$.

You can use this for the other two exercises.

Comment: This will not work for the product.

Comment: @ClementC. But if $f$, $g$, would be non-negative (which is true in my case since these are probabilities), the product can be shown to be nondecreasing, right? Could you point me to a text book about such a proof? I simply need to cite it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is just the general approach, for non-negative functions you are right, you can obviously use exactly the same path as for the additivity (for negative functions you'd have to take care of what happens with the $\leq \geq$). I'm not sure if you can find anything like this in a paper, as it is quite trivial.

Comment: @FrankMerzen  Then it is true. Take $x\leq y$ (assuming both $f,g$ are non-decreasing). Then $0\leq f(x) \leq f(y)$, and $0\leq g(x) \leq g(y)$. Multiply the first inequalities by the **non-negative** number $g(x)$: $$ 0\leq f(x)g(x) \leq f(y)g(x).$$ Multiply the second by the **non-negative** number $f(y)$:  $$0\leq f(y)g(x) \leq f(y)g(y),$$ Combine the two inequalities obtained:
$$ 0\leq f(x)g(x) \leq f(y)g(x) \leq f(y)g(y).$$
This proves that if $x\leq y$, $(fg)(x) \leq (fg)(y)$. We used the non-negativity of $f,g$ to make sure that the signs of the inequalities would not flip...

Comment: Thank you a lot, guys. I am not sure how to acknowledge your help here in these comments. Can I somehow say: It answers my question?

Answer (score 0):

To prove the product,

Let $f, g$ be two monotonuous non decreasing functions.

You have for all $x_1, x_2 \in Dom_{(f\cdot g)}$ with $x_1 \geq x_2$ holds that:

$$f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$$ and $$g(x_1) \geq g(x_2 )$$

If $g(x_1) \geq g(x_2)$ means that $g(x_1)$ can be written as $g(x_1) = g(x_2)+k$ with $k \in \mathbb{R^+_0}$

To prove this, lets assume that $g(x_2) \geq 0 \implies g(x_1) \geq 0$ and analogous for $f(x_2) \geq 0 \implies f(x_1) \geq 0$

So, multiplyng by $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$ by $g(x_2)$ you have $f(x_1)g(x_2) \geq f(x_2)g(x_2)$

Since $f(x_1) \geq 0\implies f(x_1) + k \geq 0$ ( a weak inequality )

So, add up to the LHS of the inequation $f(x_1)g(x_1) + f(x_1)+k\geq f(x_2)g(x_1)$

$$f(x_1)\left[g(x_2) + k\right] \geq f(x_2)g(x_1)$$, that is

$$f(x_1)\left[g(x_1)\right] \geq f(x_2)g(x_1) = (f\cdot g)(x_1) \geq (f\cdot g)(x_2) \iff f,g$$ are monotonuous non decreasing functions $\land f(x), g(x) \geq 0 \forall x \in Dom_{(f\cdot g)}$.