# How to show a sequence is monotone

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

I have the following sequence of functions: $$f_k(x)=kx\sin\left(\frac{k^2x^2}{k+k^3x^2}\right)$$ and want to show that it converges to $x$ on [0,1] in a monotone way. I am able to show the pointwise convergence to $x$. However, I am not sure how to show that the sequence is monotone. I know that I have to show that $f_{k+1}\leq f_{k}$ or $f_{k}\leq f_{k+1}$. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's sufficient to show that $f(x,u) = u \sin[x u/(1+u^2)]$ is monotone in $u$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm not sure how to proceed because of the sin function.

Comment: @Danny Hint: $\frac{k^2x^2}{k+k^3x^2}$ takes values in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$. $\sin$ is monotonically increasing on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the product of two positive monotone functions (both non-increasing or both nondecreasing) is monotone. Observe that $nx$ is monotone and $\sin$ is also monotone (both nondecreasing) and positive on $[0,1]$ and so the product must be monotone. See [Monotonicity of the sum/product/max of two monotone functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636117/monotonicity-of-the-sum-product-max-of-two-monotone-functions).

Comment: Thank you for answer!